# LLVM unable to unroll loops [Can't unroll; loop not terminated by a conditional branch]

Tags: loops, llvm

I am getting an error `Can't unroll; loop not terminated by a conditional branch` for the following code:
`for(i=0 ; j<10 && i<5 ; i++)
        j= j+2;`

I am using the following command for unrolling loops in a file `a.bc`:
 `opt -loops -loop-rotate -loop-simplify -loop-unroll -unroll-count=3 -unroll-allow-partial -debug a.bc -o a.loop.bc`
 Is there a way to unroll loops avoiding this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this command and it should work (I have tested it on LLVM 3.6 and 3.7)

```
    opt -mem2reg  -simplifycfg  -loops  -lcssa -loop-simplify -loop-rotate   
-loop-unroll -unroll-count=3 -unroll-allow-partial -debug a.bc -o a.loop.bc
```

you need first of all ***mem2reg*** to have your bitcode converted to SSA from (if it is not already), in the other hand the loop has two conditional exiting branches and one unconditional backedge, so ***simplifycfg*** seems helpful to transform it to one-conditional backedge form which can be handled by unroll pass

Comment: we might also want to use `-unroll-threshold` to unroll bigger loops