# LLVM: how to check that there are no loops in bytecode after loop-unrolling

Tags: loops, llvm, llvm-clang, loop-unrolling, control-flow-graph

I have a number of C source code files, on which I would like to perform some type of *static analysis*. First, I need to get rid of any *loop* in the *control flow graph*, for which I use the following [one-liners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340251/llvm-unable-to-unroll-loops-cant-unroll-loop-not-terminated-by-a-conditional):

```
~$ clang -emit-llvm -c file.c -o file.bc
~$ opt -Oz -mem2reg -simplifycfg -loops -lcssa -loop-rotate -loop-unroll \
       -unroll-threshold=1000000000 -unroll-count=3000 file.bc -o target.bc
```

I would like to know whether the resulting bytecode in `target.bc` still contains some *loop*, *e.g. because it was not possible to unroll it with the given parameters*.

One option would be to use `llvm-dis`, parse the result into a *control flow graph* and then check whether any loop exists.

However, I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel and resort on existing *command-line* tools.

**Q:** Would you be able to point me one of such tools, and how to use it?