# Why is LLVM completely unrolling my loops?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization

I have a piece of code that I want to unroll by various unroll factors and then look at the resulting bitcode. To do so I'm doing the following:

1) I first compile the code using clang:

```
clang -O0 -S -emit-llvm trainingCode.cpp -o trainingCode.ll
```

2) I then run a couple of passes on the resulting bitcode (as recommended by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340251/llvm-unable-to-unroll-loops-cant-unroll-loop-not-terminated-by-a-conditional)):

```
opt -mem2reg -simplifycfg -loops -lcssa -loop-simplify -loop-rotate -inline -inline-threshold=1000000 trainingCode.ll -o trainingCode.bc > /dev/null
```

3) Finally, I run the unrolling pass:

```
opt -loop-unroll -unroll-count=2 -unroll-allow-partial trainingCode.bc -o unrolledTrainingCode.bc > /dev/null
```

I then repeat this with various unroll factors from 1 to 4.

For a simple piece of code like the following, this works *exactly* like I need it to:

```
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    volatile float checksum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        float fff = 0.112345; 

        fff *= fff;
        fff += 1.13;

        checksum += fff/10000;
    }
}
```

But I get really weird behavior when I increase the complexity/size of the body to this for instance:

```
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    volatile float checksum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        float fff = 0.112345; 

        fff *= sqrt(fff) + fff;
        fff += 1.13;
        fff *= sqrt(fff) + fff;
        fff += 17.16; 
        fff *= sqrt(fff) + fff;
        fff += 15.13; 
        fff *= sqrt(fff) + fff;
        fff += 21.13; 
        fff *= sqrt(fff) + fff;
        fff += 81.13; 
        fff *= sqrt(fff) + fff;
        fff += 11.13; 
        fff *= sqrt(fff) + fff;
        fff += 81.13; 
        fff *= sqrt(fff) + fff;
        fff += 11.13; 
        fff *= sqrt(fff) + fff;
        fff += 91.13; 
        fff *= sqrt(fff) + fff;
        fff += 11.13; 

        checksum += (fff + i)/10000;
    }
}
```

For unroll factors of 1-2, everything works fine, but if I try to unroll using a factor greater than 2, LLVM *completely* unrolls the loop. This happens for *any* loop with sufficiently large of a body. For instance, this is (an excerpt) of the resulting bitcode of using any unroll factor greater than 2 for the code directly above:

```
; ModuleID = 'unrolledtrainingCode3.bc'
source_filename = "p1HighComplexity.cpp"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

; Function Attrs: norecurse uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %checksum = alloca float, align 4
  store volatile float 0.000000e+00, float* %checksum, align 4
  br label %for.body

for.body:                                         ; preds = %entry
  %call.i = call float @sqrtf(float 0x3FBCC2A460000000) #2
  %add = fadd float %call.i, 0x3FBCC2A460000000
  %mul = fmul float 0x3FBCC2A460000000, %add
  %conv = fpext float %mul to double
  %add1 = fadd double %conv, 1.130000e+00
  %conv2 = fptrunc double %add1 to float
  %call.i2 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv2) #2
  %add4 = fadd float %call.i2, %conv2
  %mul5 = fmul float %conv2, %add4
  %conv6 = fpext float %mul5 to double
  %add7 = fadd double %conv6, 1.716000e+01
  %conv8 = fptrunc double %add7 to float
  %call.i3 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv8) #2
  %add10 = fadd float %call.i3, %conv8
  %mul11 = fmul float %conv8, %add10
  %conv12 = fpext float %mul11 to double
  %add13 = fadd double %conv12, 1.513000e+01
  %conv14 = fptrunc double %add13 to float
  %call.i4 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv14) #2
  %add16 = fadd float %call.i4, %conv14
  %mul17 = fmul float %conv14, %add16
  %conv18 = fpext float %mul17 to double
  %add19 = fadd double %conv18, 2.113000e+01
  %conv20 = fptrunc double %add19 to float
  %call.i5 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv20) #2
  %add22 = fadd float %call.i5, %conv20
  %mul23 = fmul float %conv20, %add22
  %conv24 = fpext float %mul23 to double
  %add25 = fadd double %conv24, 0x40544851EB851EB8
  %conv26 = fptrunc double %add25 to float
  %call.i6 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv26) #2
  %add28 = fadd float %call.i6, %conv26
  %mul29 = fmul float %conv26, %add28
  %conv30 = fpext float %mul29 to double
  %add31 = fadd double %conv30, 1.113000e+01
  %conv32 = fptrunc double %add31 to float
  %call.i7 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv32) #2
  %add34 = fadd float %call.i7, %conv32
  %mul35 = fmul float %conv32, %add34
  %conv36 = fpext float %mul35 to double
  %add37 = fadd double %conv36, 0x40544851EB851EB8
  %conv38 = fptrunc double %add37 to float
  %call.i8 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv38) #2
  %add40 = fadd float %call.i8, %conv38
  %mul41 = fmul float %conv38, %add40
  %conv42 = fpext float %mul41 to double
  %add43 = fadd double %conv42, 1.113000e+01
  %conv44 = fptrunc double %add43 to float
  %call.i9 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv44) #2
  %add46 = fadd float %call.i9, %conv44
  %mul47 = fmul float %conv44, %add46
  %conv48 = fpext float %mul47 to double
  %add49 = fadd double %conv48, 0x4056C851EB851EB8
  %conv50 = fptrunc double %add49 to float
  %call.i10 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv50) #2
  %add52 = fadd float %call.i10, %conv50
  %mul53 = fmul float %conv50, %add52
  %conv54 = fpext float %mul53 to double
  %add55 = fadd double %conv54, 1.113000e+01
  %conv56 = fptrunc double %add55 to float
  %div = fdiv float %conv56, 1.000000e+04
  %0 = load volatile float, float* %checksum, align 4
  %add57 = fadd float %0, %div
  store volatile float %add57, float* %checksum, align 4
  %call.i.1 = call float @sqrtf(float 0x3FBCC2A460000000) #2
  %add.1 = fadd float %call.i.1, 0x3FBCC2A460000000
  %mul.1 = fmul float 0x3FBCC2A460000000, %add.1
  %conv.1 = fpext float %mul.1 to double
  %add1.1 = fadd double %conv.1, 1.130000e+00
  %conv2.1 = fptrunc double %add1.1 to float
  %call.i2.1 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv2.1) #2
  %add4.1 = fadd float %call.i2.1, %conv2.1
  %mul5.1 = fmul float %conv2.1, %add4.1
  %conv6.1 = fpext float %mul5.1 to double
  %add7.1 = fadd double %conv6.1, 1.716000e+01
  %conv8.1 = fptrunc double %add7.1 to float
  %call.i3.1 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv8.1) #2
  %add10.1 = fadd float %call.i3.1, %conv8.1
  %mul11.1 = fmul float %conv8.1, %add10.1
  %conv12.1 = fpext float %mul11.1 to double
  %add13.1 = fadd double %conv12.1, 1.513000e+01
  %conv14.1 = fptrunc double %add13.1 to float
  %call.i4.1 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv14.1) #2
  %add16.1 = fadd float %call.i4.1, %conv14.1
  %mul17.1 = fmul float %conv14.1, %add16.1
  %conv18.1 = fpext float %mul17.1 to double
  %add19.1 = fadd double %conv18.1, 2.113000e+01
  %conv20.1 = fptrunc double %add19.1 to float
  %call.i5.1 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv20.1) #2
  %add22.1 = fadd float %call.i5.1, %conv20.1
  %mul23.1 = fmul float %conv20.1, %add22.1
  %conv24.1 = fpext float %mul23.1 to double
  %add25.1 = fadd double %conv24.1, 0x40544851EB851EB8
  %conv26.1 = fptrunc double %add25.1 to float
  %call.i6.1 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv26.1) #2
  %add28.1 = fadd float %call.i6.1, %conv26.1
  %mul29.1 = fmul float %conv26.1, %add28.1
  %conv30.1 = fpext float %mul29.1 to double
  %add31.1 = fadd double %conv30.1, 1.113000e+01
  %conv32.1 = fptrunc double %add31.1 to float
  %call.i7.1 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv32.1) #2
  %add34.1 = fadd float %call.i7.1, %conv32.1
  %mul35.1 = fmul float %conv32.1, %add34.1
  %conv36.1 = fpext float %mul35.1 to double
  %add37.1 = fadd double %conv36.1, 0x40544851EB851EB8
  %conv38.1 = fptrunc double %add37.1 to float
  %call.i8.1 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv38.1) #2
  %add40.1 = fadd float %call.i8.1, %conv38.1
  %mul41.1 = fmul float %conv38.1, %add40.1
  %conv42.1 = fpext float %mul41.1 to double
  %add43.1 = fadd double %conv42.1, 1.113000e+01
  %conv44.1 = fptrunc double %add43.1 to float
  %call.i9.1 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv44.1) #2
  %add46.1 = fadd float %call.i9.1, %conv44.1
  %mul47.1 = fmul float %conv44.1, %add46.1
  %conv48.1 = fpext float %mul47.1 to double
  %add49.1 = fadd double %conv48.1, 0x4056C851EB851EB8
  %conv50.1 = fptrunc double %add49.1 to float
  %call.i10.1 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv50.1) #2
  %add52.1 = fadd float %call.i10.1, %conv50.1
  %mul53.1 = fmul float %conv50.1, %add52.1
  %conv54.1 = fpext float %mul53.1 to double
  %add55.1 = fadd double %conv54.1, 1.113000e+01
  %conv56.1 = fptrunc double %add55.1 to float
  %div.1 = fdiv float %conv56.1, 1.000000e+04
  %1 = load volatile float, float* %checksum, align 4
  %add57.1 = fadd float %1, %div.1
  store volatile float %add57.1, float* %checksum, align 4
  %call.i.2 = call float @sqrtf(float 0x3FBCC2A460000000) #2
  %add.2 = fadd float %call.i.2, 0x3FBCC2A460000000
  %mul.2 = fmul float 0x3FBCC2A460000000, %add.2
  %conv.2 = fpext float %mul.2 to double
  %add1.2 = fadd double %conv.2, 1.130000e+00
  %conv2.2 = fptrunc double %add1.2 to float
  %call.i2.2 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv2.2) #2
  %add4.2 = fadd float %call.i2.2, %conv2.2
  %mul5.2 = fmul float %conv2.2, %add4.2
  %conv6.2 = fpext float %mul5.2 to double
  %add7.2 = fadd double %conv6.2, 1.716000e+01
  %conv8.2 = fptrunc double %add7.2 to float
  %call.i3.2 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv8.2) #2
  %add10.2 = fadd float %call.i3.2, %conv8.2
  %mul11.2 = fmul float %conv8.2, %add10.2
  %conv12.2 = fpext float %mul11.2 to double
  %add13.2 = fadd double %conv12.2, 1.513000e+01
  %conv14.2 = fptrunc double %add13.2 to float
  %call.i4.2 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv14.2) #2
  %add16.2 = fadd float %call.i4.2, %conv14.2
  %mul17.2 = fmul float %conv14.2, %add16.2
  %conv18.2 = fpext float %mul17.2 to double
  %add19.2 = fadd double %conv18.2, 2.113000e+01
  %conv20.2 = fptrunc double %add19.2 to float
  %call.i5.2 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv20.2) #2
  %add22.2 = fadd float %call.i5.2, %conv20.2
  %mul23.2 = fmul float %conv20.2, %add22.2
  %conv24.2 = fpext float %mul23.2 to double
  %add25.2 = fadd double %conv24.2, 0x40544851EB851EB8
  %conv26.2 = fptrunc double %add25.2 to float
  %call.i6.2 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv26.2) #2
  %add28.2 = fadd float %call.i6.2, %conv26.2
  %mul29.2 = fmul float %conv26.2, %add28.2
  %conv30.2 = fpext float %mul29.2 to double
  %add31.2 = fadd double %conv30.2, 1.113000e+01
  %conv32.2 = fptrunc double %add31.2 to float
  %call.i7.2 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv32.2) #2
  %add34.2 = fadd float %call.i7.2, %conv32.2
  %mul35.2 = fmul float %conv32.2, %add34.2
  %conv36.2 = fpext float %mul35.2 to double
  %add37.2 = fadd double %conv36.2, 0x40544851EB851EB8
  %conv38.2 = fptrunc double %add37.2 to float
  %call.i8.2 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv38.2) #2
  %add40.2 = fadd float %call.i8.2, %conv38.2
  %mul41.2 = fmul float %conv38.2, %add40.2
  %conv42.2 = fpext float %mul41.2 to double
  %add43.2 = fadd double %conv42.2, 1.113000e+01
  %conv44.2 = fptrunc double %add43.2 to float
  %call.i9.2 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv44.2) #2
  %add46.2 = fadd float %call.i9.2, %conv44.2
  %mul47.2 = fmul float %conv44.2, %add46.2
  %conv48.2 = fpext float %mul47.2 to double
  %add49.2 = fadd double %conv48.2, 0x4056C851EB851EB8
  %conv50.2 = fptrunc double %add49.2 to float
  %call.i10.2 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv50.2) #2
  %add52.2 = fadd float %call.i10.2, %conv50.2
  %mul53.2 = fmul float %conv50.2, %add52.2
  %conv54.2 = fpext float %mul53.2 to double
  %add55.2 = fadd double %conv54.2, 1.113000e+01
  %conv56.2 = fptrunc double %add55.2 to float
  %div.2 = fdiv float %conv56.2, 1.000000e+04
  %2 = load volatile float, float* %checksum, align 4
  %add57.2 = fadd float %2, %div.2
  store volatile float %add57.2, float* %checksum, align 4
  %call.i.3 = call float @sqrtf(float 0x3FBCC2A460000000) #2
  %add.3 = fadd float %call.i.3, 0x3FBCC2A460000000
  %mul.3 = fmul float 0x3FBCC2A460000000, %add.3
  %conv.3 = fpext float %mul.3 to double
  %add1.3 = fadd double %conv.3, 1.130000e+00
  %conv2.3 = fptrunc double %add1.3 to float
  %call.i2.3 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv2.3) #2
  %add4.3 = fadd float %call.i2.3, %conv2.3
  %mul5.3 = fmul float %conv2.3, %add4.3
  %conv6.3 = fpext float %mul5.3 to double
  %add7.3 = fadd double %conv6.3, 1.716000e+01
  %conv8.3 = fptrunc double %add7.3 to float
  %call.i3.3 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv8.3) #2
  %add10.3 = fadd float %call.i3.3, %conv8.3
  %mul11.3 = fmul float %conv8.3, %add10.3
  %conv12.3 = fpext float %mul11.3 to double
  %add13.3 = fadd double %conv12.3, 1.513000e+01
  %conv14.3 = fptrunc double %add13.3 to float
  %call.i4.3 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv14.3) #2
  %add16.3 = fadd float %call.i4.3, %conv14.3
  %mul17.3 = fmul float %conv14.3, %add16.3
  %conv18.3 = fpext float %mul17.3 to double
  %add19.3 = fadd double %conv18.3, 2.113000e+01
  %conv20.3 = fptrunc double %add19.3 to float
  %call.i5.3 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv20.3) #2
  %add22.3 = fadd float %call.i5.3, %conv20.3
  %mul23.3 = fmul float %conv20.3, %add22.3
  %conv24.3 = fpext float %mul23.3 to double
  %add25.3 = fadd double %conv24.3, 0x40544851EB851EB8
  %conv26.3 = fptrunc double %add25.3 to float
  %call.i6.3 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv26.3) #2
  %add28.3 = fadd float %call.i6.3, %conv26.3
  %mul29.3 = fmul float %conv26.3, %add28.3
  %conv30.3 = fpext float %mul29.3 to double
  %add31.3 = fadd double %conv30.3, 1.113000e+01
  %conv32.3 = fptrunc double %add31.3 to float
  %call.i7.3 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv32.3) #2
  %add34.3 = fadd float %call.i7.3, %conv32.3
  %mul35.3 = fmul float %conv32.3, %add34.3
  %conv36.3 = fpext float %mul35.3 to double
  %add37.3 = fadd double %conv36.3, 0x40544851EB851EB8
  %conv38.3 = fptrunc double %add37.3 to float
  %call.i8.3 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv38.3) #2
  %add40.3 = fadd float %call.i8.3, %conv38.3
  %mul41.3 = fmul float %conv38.3, %add40.3
  %conv42.3 = fpext float %mul41.3 to double
  %add43.3 = fadd double %conv42.3, 1.113000e+01
  %conv44.3 = fptrunc double %add43.3 to float
  %call.i9.3 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv44.3) #2
  %add46.3 = fadd float %call.i9.3, %conv44.3
  %mul47.3 = fmul float %conv44.3, %add46.3
  %conv48.3 = fpext float %mul47.3 to double
  %add49.3 = fadd double %conv48.3, 0x4056C851EB851EB8
  %conv50.3 = fptrunc double %add49.3 to float
  %call.i10.3 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv50.3) #2
  %add52.3 = fadd float %call.i10.3, %conv50.3
  %mul53.3 = fmul float %conv50.3, %add52.3
  %conv54.3 = fpext float %mul53.3 to double
  %add55.3 = fadd double %conv54.3, 1.113000e+01
  %conv56.3 = fptrunc double %add55.3 to float
  %div.3 = fdiv float %conv56.3, 1.000000e+04
  %3 = load volatile float, float* %checksum, align 4
  %add57.3 = fadd float %3, %div.3
  store volatile float %add57.3, float* %checksum, align 4
  %call.i.4 = call float @sqrtf(float 0x3FBCC2A460000000) #2
  %add.4 = fadd float %call.i.4, 0x3FBCC2A460000000
  %mul.4 = fmul float 0x3FBCC2A460000000, %add.4
  %conv.4 = fpext float %mul.4 to double
  %add1.4 = fadd double %conv.4, 1.130000e+00
  %conv2.4 = fptrunc double %add1.4 to float
  %call.i2.4 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv2.4) #2
  %add4.4 = fadd float %call.i2.4, %conv2.4
  %mul5.4 = fmul float %conv2.4, %add4.4
  %conv6.4 = fpext float %mul5.4 to double
  %add7.4 = fadd double %conv6.4, 1.716000e+01
  %conv8.4 = fptrunc double %add7.4 to float
  %call.i3.4 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv8.4) #2
  %add10.4 = fadd float %call.i3.4, %conv8.4
  %mul11.4 = fmul float %conv8.4, %add10.4
  %conv12.4 = fpext float %mul11.4 to double
  %add13.4 = fadd double %conv12.4, 1.513000e+01
  %conv14.4 = fptrunc double %add13.4 to float
  %call.i4.4 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv14.4) #2
  %add16.4 = fadd float %call.i4.4, %conv14.4
  %mul17.4 = fmul float %conv14.4, %add16.4
  %conv18.4 = fpext float %mul17.4 to double
  %add19.4 = fadd double %conv18.4, 2.113000e+01
  %conv20.4 = fptrunc double %add19.4 to float
  %call.i5.4 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv20.4) #2
  %add22.4 = fadd float %call.i5.4, %conv20.4
  %mul23.4 = fmul float %conv20.4, %add22.4
  %conv24.4 = fpext float %mul23.4 to double
  %add25.4 = fadd double %conv24.4, 0x40544851EB851EB8
  %conv26.4 = fptrunc double %add25.4 to float
  %call.i6.4 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv26.4) #2
  %add28.4 = fadd float %call.i6.4, %conv26.4
  %mul29.4 = fmul float %conv26.4, %add28.4
  %conv30.4 = fpext float %mul29.4 to double
  %add31.4 = fadd double %conv30.4, 1.113000e+01
  %conv32.4 = fptrunc double %add31.4 to float
  %call.i7.4 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv32.4) #2
  %add34.4 = fadd float %call.i7.4, %conv32.4
  %mul35.4 = fmul float %conv32.4, %add34.4
  %conv36.4 = fpext float %mul35.4 to double
  %add37.4 = fadd double %conv36.4, 0x40544851EB851EB8
  %conv38.4 = fptrunc double %add37.4 to float
  %call.i8.4 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv38.4) #2
  %add40.4 = fadd float %call.i8.4, %conv38.4
  %mul41.4 = fmul float %conv38.4, %add40.4
  %conv42.4 = fpext float %mul41.4 to double
  %add43.4 = fadd double %conv42.4, 1.113000e+01
  %conv44.4 = fptrunc double %add43.4 to float
  %call.i9.4 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv44.4) #2
  %add46.4 = fadd float %call.i9.4, %conv44.4
  %mul47.4 = fmul float %conv44.4, %add46.4
  %conv48.4 = fpext float %mul47.4 to double
  %add49.4 = fadd double %conv48.4, 0x4056C851EB851EB8
  %conv50.4 = fptrunc double %add49.4 to float
  %call.i10.4 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv50.4) #2
  %add52.4 = fadd float %call.i10.4, %conv50.4
  %mul53.4 = fmul float %conv50.4, %add52.4
  %conv54.4 = fpext float %mul53.4 to double
  %add55.4 = fadd double %conv54.4, 1.113000e+01
  %conv56.4 = fptrunc double %add55.4 to float
  %div.4 = fdiv float %conv56.4, 1.000000e+04
  %4 = load volatile float, float* %checksum, align 4
  %add57.4 = fadd float %4, %div.4
  store volatile float %add57.4, float* %checksum, align 4
  %call.i.5 = call float @sqrtf(float 0x3FBCC2A460000000) #2
  %add.5 = fadd float %call.i.5, 0x3FBCC2A460000000
  %mul.5 = fmul float 0x3FBCC2A460000000, %add.5
  %conv.5 = fpext float %mul.5 to double
  %add1.5 = fadd double %conv.5, 1.130000e+00
  %conv2.5 = fptrunc double %add1.5 to float
  %call.i2.5 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv2.5) #2
  %add4.5 = fadd float %call.i2.5, %conv2.5
  %mul5.5 = fmul float %conv2.5, %add4.5
  %conv6.5 = fpext float %mul5.5 to double
  %add7.5 = fadd double %conv6.5, 1.716000e+01
  %conv8.5 = fptrunc double %add7.5 to float
  %call.i3.5 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv8.5) #2
  %add10.5 = fadd float %call.i3.5, %conv8.5
  %mul11.5 = fmul float %conv8.5, %add10.5
  %conv12.5 = fpext float %mul11.5 to double
  %add13.5 = fadd double %conv12.5, 1.513000e+01
  %conv14.5 = fptrunc double %add13.5 to float
  %call.i4.5 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv14.5) #2
  %add16.5 = fadd float %call.i4.5, %conv14.5
  %mul17.5 = fmul float %conv14.5, %add16.5
  %conv18.5 = fpext float %mul17.5 to double
  %add19.5 = fadd double %conv18.5, 2.113000e+01
  %conv20.5 = fptrunc double %add19.5 to float
  %call.i5.5 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv20.5) #2
  %add22.5 = fadd float %call.i5.5, %conv20.5
  %mul23.5 = fmul float %conv20.5, %add22.5
  %conv24.5 = fpext float %mul23.5 to double
  %add25.5 = fadd double %conv24.5, 0x40544851EB851EB8
  %conv26.5 = fptrunc double %add25.5 to float
  %call.i6.5 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv26.5) #2
  %add28.5 = fadd float %call.i6.5, %conv26.5
  %mul29.5 = fmul float %conv26.5, %add28.5
  %conv30.5 = fpext float %mul29.5 to double
  %add31.5 = fadd double %conv30.5, 1.113000e+01
  %conv32.5 = fptrunc double %add31.5 to float
  %call.i7.5 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv32.5) #2
  %add34.5 = fadd float %call.i7.5, %conv32.5
  %mul35.5 = fmul float %conv32.5, %add34.5
  %conv36.5 = fpext float %mul35.5 to double
  %add37.5 = fadd double %conv36.5, 0x40544851EB851EB8
  %conv38.5 = fptrunc double %add37.5 to float
  %call.i8.5 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv38.5) #2
  %add40.5 = fadd float %call.i8.5, %conv38.5
  %mul41.5 = fmul float %conv38.5, %add40.5
  %conv42.5 = fpext float %mul41.5 to double
  %add43.5 = fadd double %conv42.5, 1.113000e+01
  %conv44.5 = fptrunc double %add43.5 to float
  %call.i9.5 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv44.5) #2
  %add46.5 = fadd float %call.i9.5, %conv44.5
  %mul47.5 = fmul float %conv44.5, %add46.5
  %conv48.5 = fpext float %mul47.5 to double
  %add49.5 = fadd double %conv48.5, 0x4056C851EB851EB8
  %conv50.5 = fptrunc double %add49.5 to float
  %call.i10.5 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv50.5) #2
  %add52.5 = fadd float %call.i10.5, %conv50.5
  %mul53.5 = fmul float %conv50.5, %add52.5
  %conv54.5 = fpext float %mul53.5 to double
  %add55.5 = fadd double %conv54.5, 1.113000e+01
  %conv56.5 = fptrunc double %add55.5 to float
  %div.5 = fdiv float %conv56.5, 1.000000e+04
  %5 = load volatile float, float* %checksum, align 4
  %add57.5 = fadd float %5, %div.5
  store volatile float %add57.5, float* %checksum, align 4
  %call.i.6 = call float @sqrtf(float 0x3FBCC2A460000000) #2
  %add.6 = fadd float %call.i.6, 0x3FBCC2A460000000
  %mul.6 = fmul float 0x3FBCC2A460000000, %add.6
  %conv.6 = fpext float %mul.6 to double
  %add1.6 = fadd double %conv.6, 1.130000e+00
  %conv2.6 = fptrunc double %add1.6 to float
  %call.i2.6 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv2.6) #2
  %add4.6 = fadd float %call.i2.6, %conv2.6
  %mul5.6 = fmul float %conv2.6, %add4.6
  %conv6.6 = fpext float %mul5.6 to double
  %add7.6 = fadd double %conv6.6, 1.716000e+01
  %conv8.6 = fptrunc double %add7.6 to float
  %call.i3.6 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv8.6) #2
  %add10.6 = fadd float %call.i3.6, %conv8.6
  %mul11.6 = fmul float %conv8.6, %add10.6
  %conv12.6 = fpext float %mul11.6 to double
  %add13.6 = fadd double %conv12.6, 1.513000e+01
  %conv14.6 = fptrunc double %add13.6 to float
  %call.i4.6 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv14.6) #2
  %add16.6 = fadd float %call.i4.6, %conv14.6
  %mul17.6 = fmul float %conv14.6, %add16.6
  %conv18.6 = fpext float %mul17.6 to double
  %add19.6 = fadd double %conv18.6, 2.113000e+01
  %conv20.6 = fptrunc double %add19.6 to float
  %call.i5.6 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv20.6) #2
  %add22.6 = fadd float %call.i5.6, %conv20.6
  %mul23.6 = fmul float %conv20.6, %add22.6
  %conv24.6 = fpext float %mul23.6 to double
  %add25.6 = fadd double %conv24.6, 0x40544851EB851EB8
  %conv26.6 = fptrunc double %add25.6 to float
  %call.i6.6 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv26.6) #2
  %add28.6 = fadd float %call.i6.6, %conv26.6
  %mul29.6 = fmul float %conv26.6, %add28.6
  %conv30.6 = fpext float %mul29.6 to double
  %add31.6 = fadd double %conv30.6, 1.113000e+01
  %conv32.6 = fptrunc double %add31.6 to float
  %call.i7.6 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv32.6) #2
  %add34.6 = fadd float %call.i7.6, %conv32.6
  %mul35.6 = fmul float %conv32.6, %add34.6
  %conv36.6 = fpext float %mul35.6 to double
  %add37.6 = fadd double %conv36.6, 0x40544851EB851EB8
  %conv38.6 = fptrunc double %add37.6 to float
  %call.i8.6 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv38.6) #2
  %add40.6 = fadd float %call.i8.6, %conv38.6
  %mul41.6 = fmul float %conv38.6, %add40.6
  %conv42.6 = fpext float %mul41.6 to double
  %add43.6 = fadd double %conv42.6, 1.113000e+01
  %conv44.6 = fptrunc double %add43.6 to float
  %call.i9.6 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv44.6) #2
  %add46.6 = fadd float %call.i9.6, %conv44.6
  %mul47.6 = fmul float %conv44.6, %add46.6
  %conv48.6 = fpext float %mul47.6 to double
  %add49.6 = fadd double %conv48.6, 0x4056C851EB851EB8
  %conv50.6 = fptrunc double %add49.6 to float
  %call.i10.6 = call float @sqrtf(float %conv50.6) #2
  %add52.6 = fadd float %call.i10.6, %conv50.6
  %mul53.6 = fmul float %conv50.6, %add52.6
  %conv54.6 = fpext float %mul53.6 to double
  %add55.6 = fadd double %conv54.6, 1.113000e+01
  %conv56.6 = fptrunc double %add55.6 to float
  %div.6 = fdiv float %conv56.6, 1.000000e+04
  %6 = load volatile float, float* %checksum, align 4
  %add57.6 = fadd float %6, %div.6
```

As you can see, the loop was *fully* unrolled, despite me specifying an unroll factor of 3. I was hoping someone would have some insight into why this was happening...

Comment: all the variables are declared as `float` but all the literals are `double`.  Suggest remembering to append 'f' to each of the literals

Comment: the function `sqrt()` expects a `double` parameter and returns a `double` result.  You can avoid all the resulting conversions by replacing 'sqrt' with 'sqrtf'

Comment: @user3629249 Unfortunately, the issue remains even if I have a completely different body with no floating point operations...

Comment: My comment about which function to call was a suggestion on improving the code, NOT a fix for the loop unrolling.  BTW: what exactly are the parameters to the compile step, that you are using?

Comment: @user3629249 I'm using `clang -O0 -S -emit-llvm trainingCode.cpp -o trainingCode.ll`

Answer (score 1):

LLVM has different heuristics for determining whether to unroll and whether to unroll fully, because unrolling a loop fully is often more beneficial than unrolling it partially, particularly if the trip count is fixed and known at compile time, because then all the checks and branches can be eliminated.

My quick search only turned up the [source code](http://llvm.org/doxygen/LoopUnrollPass_8cpp_source.html) and not the documentation, 
but I think full unrolling is limited by a different setting: `-unroll-full-max-count`.